# How Jozza Bombsight worked?

Tags: aircraft-systems

I'm looking some information about the so called Jozza Bombsight used for example on board of the Savoia-Marchetti SM-79 during WWII. Thank you

Comment: Presumably this is a reference to the Italian WW2-era airplane "Savoia-Marchetti SM-79" (see for example https://www.historynet.com/damned-hunchbacks.htm).  You might want to add some of those details to clarify your question.

Comment: Thank you, I was interested   in how was for the pilot using it. I found many informations for example about the Bombsight on the B17 but nothing about the JOZZA...thank you,